Windows Antivirus Detects "go run main.go" Output as a Virus
I'm new to Go, and currently working through some textbooks I've bought on the topic. I use BitDefender Antivirus and it seems to be intermittently flagging go-build files as a Virus, giving this information:
"The file C:\Users\Marcus\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build591304050\b001\exe\e211.exe is infected with Gen:Variant.Tedy.601131. The threat has been successfully blocked, your device is safe"
This happens when I run go run main.go in my gitbash console. What is the workaround? Go creates a new directory in \AppData\Local\Temp each time the command is ran, so I'm wary to add the entire Temp folder as an exclusion in my antivirus.
I tried to set the go env variable GOBIN to a directory called "GOTMPDIR" within \Temp.
cmd
set GOBIN=C:\GOTMPDIR
This did not change the go env variable and when its value is checked with go env GOBIN it prints an empty line.

Never use go run with filename arguments. Especially not if you are new to Go.

I found an answer for my particular use case. I run using a GitBash terminal in my vscode project (or normal GitBash window). To fix it I edited the bashrc file -> nano ~/.bashrc and added line "export GOTMPDIR="Path\To\Dir".
As it turns out GOTMPDIR is a go env variable which determines the directory where intermediate build files are stored temporarily. After running go run main.go in my projects, the output is sent to the console accordingly, but the temporary directory remains empty.
This fix has allowed me to continue the learning process, but I'm not certain that this fix will work for more advanced use cases or all Antivirus software.
